# Using Kafka's Log Compaction, what can I do to guarantee consumers don't miss messages, if they are not lagging behind by some defined timelimit?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

From this : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction , it is sort of clear that, if I enable log compaction, there is no guarantee what stays in the "head" of the log. 
So, given I have consumers - e.g : Audit consumers, how can I ensure I will maintain all messages atleast for (say) 7 days, only messages older than that, should be eligible for compaction?

Non of the configurations exposed w.r.t log.compaction allows me to give such a guarantee. Is this possible?

Comment: Basically : I want to give a guarantee such as : "If a consumer is not lagging behind more than 2 days, he is guaranteed to see each and every message, post that - he will only see the latest message".

Comment: Why do you want to used log compaction at all and not just keep all messages for some time?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax to have an ability to identifies list of keys changed from a certain point in time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't this solve your problem - setting it to 7 days?

"The log cleaner can be configured to retain a minimum amount of the uncompacted "head" of the log. This is enabled by setting the compaction time lag.

`log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms`

This can be used to prevent messages newer than a minimum message age from being subject to compaction."

(from http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction)

Comment: nice, looks like this was introduced recently!

Answer (score 0):

You could setup two topics. One without log compaction, and with a 7 day retention period. The other with log compaction on. A simple Kafka Streams app could read from the un-compacted topic and write to the compacted topic. If your client apps don't want to deal with two topics you could write a wrapper that makes the two topics look like one continuous log.

Comment: Yes, that's one workaround that I thought off, but was wondering if kafka has a configuration to manage both aspects on the same topic, it would be kind of nice.

Comment: You could also store the last message for each key in a nosql database and keep all the un-compacted messages in a singe topic for 7 days.